# ASP.NET MVC3 - RAZOR - Date format validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I'm new to MVC3 - and cannot figure out why the Date format validation is not working on client-side i.e., if I manually change the text box and input an invalid format date. I'm using jQuery date picker for this field. The strange thing is that the Required Field Validation is working.

Can someone please let me know what's wrong with this code?

Thanks!

VIEWMODEL

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyyy")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ADate { get; set; }
```

VIEW

```
        @Html.TextBox("ADate", Model.ADate.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "ADate" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ADate, "*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataType and DisplayFormat only works when using DisplayFor or EditorFor, and not with a TextBox.  You can't set a class name with EditorFor, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can use underlying `TextBoxFor()` and specify a class name

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADate, new { @class = "ADate" })
```